# R - transliterating into German alphabet using stri_trans_general()

Tags: r, stringi

I have a large number of names, mostly using a German character set, i.e., ASCII plus ä,ö,ü,ß. Some names use special characters (e.g. ğ) which I would like to transliterate into the German version. So, "Özoğuz" should become "Özoguz".

I have tried

```
stri_trans_general("Özoğuz", "de-ASCII")
```

but that will result in "Oezoguz" not the desired "Özoguz".

Comment: "ğ" was just an example. There is a large list of characters from other languages (å, æ, œ, ø, ç, ...) which I would like to transliterate. I want to avoid having to identify this set of characters manually.

Comment: Can you give more examples?

Comment: So to be clear you want to keep the diacritic on the  `Ö` but not on the `ğ`? Is that because of case or is it to do with the German alphabet? More generally what are the rules for what you want to keep or change? If you can find a rule list consistent with this in the [ICU transforms documentation](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/transforms/general/) then you can supply this to `stringi` (for full range of IDs run `stringi::stri_trans_list()`). If not I can't see how you can avoid manually identifying the character set.

Comment: You may start from here `string = c("Özoğuz", "görmek", "içmek", "düşünmek");  source = "şçİğÇŞı"; change = "scIgCSi"; chartr(source, change, string)`.

Comment: @SamR "Is that because of case or is it to do with the German alphabet": The german alphabet has ä, ö, ü and ß but no ğ, ´é and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `de-ASCII` rule set translates `Ö` to `Oe`.  If you want to deviate from this rule but otherwise maintain the German ASCII rule set, the `stringi` [docs](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/stringi/html/stri_trans_general.html) state that *Custom rule-based transliteration is also supported*.

We can define rules which translate (upper and lower case) `Ö` to a third character, apply the `de-ASCII` rules to everything else, then translates the third character back to `Ö`:

```r
id <- "
    Ö > \u2135;
    ö > \u2136;
    :: de-ASCII;
    \u2135 >  Ö;
    \u2136 > ö
"

stringi::stri_trans_general("Özoğuz", id, rules = TRUE)
# [1] "Özoguz"
```

I have used `"ℵ"` and `"ℶ"` for upper and lower case `Ö` respectively, but any utf-8 characters you are sure will not be in your string should work.

Comment: Great, this works. I am just wondering why it has to be so complicated? Seems to be a pretty straightforward problem for people working with German (or any other language that has certain non-ASCII characters but not others...)